# How to convert Google Map to PDF using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-plugins

Does there is any javascript code to convert generated google map into PDF using Javascript or any JS library?

Any help will be appreciated, and it will be more helpful if there is demo of such scenario.

Comment: Have you seen this one Mazzu? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647833/google-maps-and-pdf

This is a nice one as well: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27510/export-map-to-pdf-using-esri-javascript-api

Comment: @LuisGouveia, yeah I have seen it but actually it doesn't relates

Comment: @LuisGouveia, can your provide any further details on it?

Answer (score 2):

If your okay with multiple libraries, you could try [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) to snapshot the html page then use node.js to [convert to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213902/convert-png-image-to-pdf-in-nodejs-canvas).

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution using 2 libraries:
 jspdf.min.js and html2canvas.js.
add these to your index.html:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

```
  function export_to_pdf() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img =canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");
            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
            pdf.save('a4.pdf')
        }
    });
}
```

explanation:

1. html2canvas takes body or any other DOM element and creates a canvas object.
2. canvas.toDataURL creates an image string.
3. pdf.addImage adds the image to pdf object.
4. pdf.save(), downloads the image.

Comment: Thanks! I have used this today. Much more easier than phantom.js . Just give your map DIV id to the parameter.